# Subscript Notation on Real Numbers

Tags: integration, notation, fourier-analysis

I was reading a wiki page on [oscillatory integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillatory_integral) and I came across two notations I am unfamiliar with.

$$\Bbb R_{x}^{n}\ \times \ R_{\zeta}^{N}$$

$$S_{1,0}^{m}(\Bbb R_{x}^{n}\ \times \ R_{\zeta}^{N})$$

Firstly, what do the subscripts for the real numbers mean? Also what is $S_{1,0}^{m}$ and what does the second notation mean? There is no explanation on the page and trying to search around has not gotten me far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscripts appear be simply the names of the variables. For the definition of $S^m_{1,0} = S^m$, quote from [Pseudo-Differential Operators and Symmetries](https://books.google.es/books?id=2SG4BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=%22symbol+class%22+operator&source=bl&ots=L0Iv5Bsds1&sig=ACfU3U189nYFSJtT_xLVraBOy35cEfOu2g&hl=es&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjjlbSAiL_kAhVdBGMBHW7ZDjEQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22symbol%20class%22%20operator&f=false):

**Definition** (**Symbol Classes** $S^m(\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n)$). We will say that $a\in S^m(\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n)$ if $a = a(x,\xi)$ is smooth in $\Bbb R^n\times\Bbb R^n$ and if the estimates
$$|\partial^\beta_x\partial^\alpha_\xi a(x,\xi)|\le A_{\alpha,\beta}(1 + |\xi|)^{m - |\alpha|}$$
hold for all $\alpha,\beta$ [[multi-indexes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation)] and $x,\xi\in\Bbb R^n$. Constants $A_{\alpha,\beta}$ may depend on $a,\alpha,\beta$, but no on $x,\xi$.

Answer (score 2):

At the bottom of the [linked Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oscillatory_integral), there is a set of references:

[image]

The second reference is to an article which is [freely available online](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.acta/1485889699).  The notation $S_{\varrho,\delta}^{m}(X\times\mathbb{R}^N)$ is defined on page 83:

> *Definition 1.1.1.* Let $m$, $\varrho$, $\delta$ be real numbers with $0\le \varrho \le 1$, $0\le \delta \le 1$.  Then we denote by $S_{\varrho,\delta}^{m}(X\times\mathbb{R}^N)$ the set of all $a \in C^{\infty}(X\times\mathbb{R}^N)$ such that... [technical conditions follow].

The technical conditions basically give bounds on how large the derivatives can be on compact subsets of $X$, where $X$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (note that the first coordinate comes from $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, while the second coordinate comes from $\mathbb{R}^N$—it appears that $n$ and $N$ may be distinct).  The sets defined here are the *symbols* (of order $m$ and type $\varrho, \delta$).  $S^{\infty}_{\varrho,\delta}$ is the union of all symbols, taken over the order $m$.

Regarding the meaning of $\mathbb{R}_x^n$ and $R_\xi^N$, I have two comments:

1. It appears that there is a typo in the Wikipedia article, and that $R_{\xi}^N$ should really be $\mathbb{R}_{\xi}^N$.  However, I don't know a whole lot about oscillattory integrals, nor the notational conventions of the field, so this is only a guess.
2. From context, it appears that the subscripts denote the names of the variables which are taken from the given coordinate.  For example, if
   $$ a \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}_x^n \times \mathbb{R}_{\xi}^N),$$
   then $a$ is function with domain $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^N$, where $a$ takes as input an ordered pair $(x,\xi)$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\xi \in \mathbb{R}^N$.  This appears to be a shorthand notation used to remind the reader where the variables come from.

Comment: What is $C^{\infty}$ in this case? Is it the codomain of $a$? I feel like I might be in over my head here.

Comment: $C^\infty(X)$ is the set of all smooth functions on the domain $X$.  That is, $C^{\infty}(X)$ consists of all functions $u : X \to \mathbb{R}$ (or $\to \mathbb{C}$) such that $D^{\alpha}u$ is continuous for any multiindex $\alpha$ (basically, $u$ has continuous derivatives of all order---if $X$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then $u^{(n)}$ is continuous for all natural numbers $n$).  This is fairly standard notation in various branches of analysis.

Comment: Perfect excellent explanation. thank you